# Создать список чисел из строки с числами через пробел

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, строки, списки

Имеется строка:

> '45 30 55 20 80 20'.

Необходимо создать массив из чисел входящих в данную строку:

> [45, 30, 55, 20, 80, 20].

Долго думал и пришел только к такому коду, только не работает:

```
for i in range(len(q)):
    if q[i]!=(' '):
        e+=q[i]
    else:
        w.append(int(e))
        e=''
 print(w)
```

проблема в том что последнюю 20 он не видит, прошу помогите

Comment: Метод split() для разделения входной строки и int() для преобразования строки в число.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Задача решена

Comment: Если притронутся к вашему коду, то тут заметно, что по причине того, что после 20 нет пробела, он всё это не видит, так что даю вам задачу: на основе придуманного вами метода создайте то, что просят в задаче.

Answer (score 13):

Можно воспользоваться генератором списка:

```
s = '45 30 55 20 80 20'
a = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
```

Answer (score 8):

**UPD.** поправлено исходя из комментариев

```
s = '45 30 55 20 80 20'
print (list(map(int, s.split())))
```

> [45, 30, 55, 20, 80, 20]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень помогли

Comment: @МоРгАн В Python 3.x `map` возвращает итератор (map object), можно вызвать на нем `list()` чтобы преобразовать в список

Comment: @jfs, да, действительно.